# how to convert multiple columns into JSON in BQ

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have data looks like below

```
empid   ename   start_date    end_date      city
101     ravi    10-Jan-2018   11-Mar-2020   New York
102    britney  10-Jul-2016   25-Mar-2021   Los angeles
```

I want to convert multiple columns into JSON format like as below

```
empid   ename      emp_attributes
101     ravi       {start_date: 10-Jan-2018, end_date: 11-Mar-2020, city: New York}
102     britney    {start_date: 10-Jul-2016, end_date: 25-Mar-2021, city: Los angeles}
```

Could you please suggest me how to write select statement to get the desired output in BQ

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may first transform these attributes into a struct using `STRUCT` then to json using `TO_JSON_STRING`

```sql
SELECT
    empid,
    ename,
    TO_JSON_STRING(STRUCT(
        start_date,
        end_date,
        city
    )) as emp_attributes
FROM
    my_table
```

Let me know if this works for you

Answer (score 2):

In many practical cases - number of columns to be put into json is greatly outnumbers columns to be left outside json. In such cases typing all columns inside to_json_string function can be not the best experience.

Consider below approach then

```
select empid, ename,
  to_json_string((
    select as struct * except(empid, ename) from unnest([t])
  )) as emp_attributes
from `project.dataset.table` t
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Very practical solution, Mickail! Thank you for that :) Just a tiny remark: I think your last SELECT keyword should be a FROM

Comment: of course :o) - just typo